# Спецсредства spring для кэширования параметров, хранящихся в БД

Tags: java, spring

Есть задача: написать класс, который при запуске проекта считывает из базы данных параметры, которые хранятся в отдельный таблице (Id - Name - Value). К этому классу обращаются другие классы, чтобы получить параметры, не обращаясь к БД. Насколько я понял, в Spring есть спецсредства для подобного. Но я ничего не нашёл. В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: В сторону самых основ Spring. Каждый spring bean по умолчанию _одиночка_, а значит реализует необходимый вам функционал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаете сервис . В нём через `Autowired` конструктор получаете репозиторий и читаете все данные в кокой-нибудь HashMap. В этом же сервисе делаете публичный метод для получения значения по ключу. И затем используете этот сервис везде где вам нужно.

```
@Service
public class ParameterService {

    private HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    public ParameterService(ParameterRepository repository) {
         foreach(Parameter p : repository.findAll()) {
             params.put(p.getName(), p.getValue());
         }
    }

    public String getParamValue(String name) {
        return params.get(name);
    }
}

@Service
public class AnotherService {

    private final ParameterService parameterService;

    @Autowired
    public ParameterService(ParameterService parameterService) {
         this.parameterService = parameterService;
    }

    public void logic() {
        String value = parameterService.getParamValue("name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Спец средств у Spring'а нет</s>, но есть у **Hibernate**. У него есть несколько уровней кэширования:

1. уровень сессий
2. кэш второго уровня - умеющий работать с разными сессиями
3. кэш запросов - так же работающий с разными сессиями, но для запросов

Первый включен по умолчанию, второй и третий нужно настраивать.  Подробнее можете почитать [здесь](http://www.izebit.ru/2015/12/hibernate.html)

Comment: Вообще-то у спринга есть функционал, который позволяет кешировать возв. значение из метода. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html

Comment: ого, все таки что то появилось